# How can I increase or decrease font size of a whole page

Tags: javascript, css

I'm using the following but it doesn't work.

```
function changeFontSize(){
        parent.frames['main'].document.body.style.fontSize = "150%";
    }
```

I hope i wouldnt have to cycle through each element on the page and give it the font size like that because that will be very inefficient

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why is the browser zoom controls (`Ctrl`+ `+` and `ctrl`+`-`) not sufficient?

Comment: @Nivas apparently not. stupid users. its in the requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following to your css file: `* {font-size:150%}`

Comment: i want to increase it or decrease it dynamically with javascript ie two buttons one for increase and one for decrease

Comment: So the font size of every element is 50% larger then its parent? That is going to result in some huge font sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`document.body.style.fontSize = "200%";`

This will set the `body` font-size to 200%. However, if you have elements with styles that explicitly set the font-size to a set unit, they will not change. You must have a proportional font-size (%/em/ex/etc) for all the elements that you want to change along with the body font-size.

Answer (score 0):

Try this jquery control:

http://www.fluidbyte.net/index.php?view=JQuery-Font-Sizer